What is the best way(Performance wise) to pass large document from one Api to another api using http client C#
I have a document docx file which is more than 30 MB. I want to send this document to one API to another API. I have tried different ways but it takes around 1 or more second for process. I need to achieve same thing in milliseconds.
What is best and time efficient way to achieve this please help me.
Below codes i have tried :
Client Side
var templatebyteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\rprajapati\Downloads\TableData-out.docx"); // template byte array 
  var authorization = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
  var Test30MBDoc = new Test30MBDoc { CurrentTime = starttime, DocArray = templatebyteArray };
  var content = Serialize(Test30MBDoc);

 using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
 {
         HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, testUrl);
         request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
         request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization[0]);
         var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
 }

Server Side
[HttpPost]
[Route("receiver1")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Test20MBDoc array)
{
    try
    {
// transport time take around 1 second 
    }
}


Second Thing i tried to send the template into chunks using multipart request"
Client Side :
 var templatebyteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\rprajapati\Downloads\TableData-out.docx");; // template byte array 

 int MAX_SUB_SIZE = 5242880; // 5*1024*1024 == 5MB
 MultipartFormDataContent multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
 int i = 1;
 foreach (byte[] chunk in templatebyteArray.Chunk(MAX_SUB_SIZE))
 {
     ByteArrayContent byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(chunk);
     byteArrayContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
     multiPartContent.Add(byteArrayContent, "byte content", $"chunk{i}");
     i++;
 }

 var authorization = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
 using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
 {
     HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, testUrl);
     request.Content = multiPartContent;
     request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization[0]);
     var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
 }

Server Side:
      [HttpPost]
        [Route("receiver")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
               //  transport time takes around 0.5 second but Need to convert chunks into template again it takes around 300 ms
         }



Hi @user24973368, Instead of reading the entire file into memory before sending it, stream the data directly from the source to the destination.

honestly, uploading 30MB in 1 seconds seems reasonable.
